# How to get xml source code from UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebView to exact source from a webpage however I can't get it to work for xml files. Here the code I'm using:

```
NSString *xml = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];
```

However this doesn't give me the XML source tags. Anyone got any ideas?

This works for html documents but not for xml documents, it seems. How can I get this working with UIWebView?

Thanks

Comment: Can you NSLog xml and paste it here? What is in your test XML document? What is the content of HTML that works for you? Is XML correctly formatted? Does it have correct invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use JavaScript, which cannot be executed in an XML document.

If you know the URL of the XML document, you can use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)URL]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *webViewBody = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(document);"];
```